# tabindex not being set when textbox has focus

Tags: input, onfocus, tabindex

I have a textbox that when focused it calls an ajax request and populates a list for the user to choose from.  Basically just recreated the dropdown using a textbox instead of a select.

The problem is that if I click on the textbox the browser does not recognize the tabindex of the input.  Instead it resets its self and starts back at 0.  If I tab to the next element tabs work fine, only when I click in the input field to give it focus does it start acting up.

I did notice last night if I put an alert in the page on the focus event that it seems to work. Guessing because the browser focuses on the elememt after I click the ok button.

has anyone heard of this before?

Answer (score 0):

found what was causing the problem.  I was calling .blur() on keydown and code was 9 or 13 (Tab/Enter).  Not sure why this would give me the problem I was having.  I would have just thought the blur event would have executed twice.  However I suppose that I was forcing blur on keydown and the current tabindex was not being set. If this is the case then If I needed to I should beable to call blur() onkeyup event.